# runtime error when adding data to arraylist

Tags: java, android

My code is running fine but when i send the value 1 to `subcat` it does not show data but it shows when I send 5 or 9. My first thought was it's because of the size so I removed and commented the image addition. But still I can't show data for `subcat=1`.

**AsyncTask**

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ArrayList<item> jsonArrayList = new ArrayList<item>();
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://avdeal.in/get_all_products.php");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                String posts = jsonObject.getString("products");
                JSONArray postsArray = new JSONArray(posts);
                if (postsArray != null) {
                    if (postsArray.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postsObject = postsArray
                                    .getJSONObject(i);
                            int subcat = postsObject.getInt("subcat_id");
                            if (subcats == 1) {
                                if (subcats == subcat) {
                                    String title = postsObject.getString("product_title");
                                    String price = postsObject.getString("product_price");
                                    String url = "http://avdeal.in/seller/upload_images/" + postsObject.getString("product_url");
                                    //InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                                    //Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                                    list.add(new item(title, price, url));
                                }
                                } else  {
                            if (subcats == subcat) {
                                String title = postsObject.getString("product_title");
                                String price = postsObject.getString("product_price");
                                String url = "http://avdeal.in/seller/upload_images/" + postsObject.getString("product_url");

                                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                                list.add(new item(title, price, url, b));
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could format your code better?

Comment: @durron597 - I know, I just formatted the OP's code

Comment: sorry about that i am working on it for very long time. have edited it so many times that it got messed up. please tell me why cant i view data when subcat=1

Comment: @Shashank, I tried to edit the body and make it more clear what you are trying to say. If I inadvertently changed the meaning of something, feel free to edit or roll it back.

Comment: @ShashankShekhar You should also check your syntax.

Comment: it looks so nice now. stackoverflow messed it up saying i cant post more than 2 urls unless my rep is 2k.

Comment: i have edited the code. now it is a running code. please tell me why it is not showing data when subcat=1

Comment: What does `subcats` equal? you have an inner `if` statement with no `else` case - so if `subcat` is >= 1 but != `subcats`, nothing will happen

Comment: i edited my code and it now shows data when the subcat=1 if i donot map the image. but i need to map the image too. this code runs fine. but i need to combine both if statements. what should i do?